# How to solve a mixed Hierarchy issue & data view-ability?

Tags: permissions, roles

We have a unique issue, where a user whom is in a Salesforce Admin role, is also one of the individuals whom enters Opportunities (Donations to our NPO).

Our issue is, that we have users with Manager roles, whom are only seeing the data in their reports that was entered by users of equal or lower Hierarchy, but not the data entered by this user whom is also an Admin.

What is the best way to go about resolving this and making the data from that user's opportunities visible to our Managers?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use a [Criteria-Based Sharing Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en_US)
.

You can create a Sharing Rule that shares Opportunities created by the System Administrator role with the Manager role.

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me.  Creating the sharing rule on Opportunity did not seem to make the Opportunity/Donation is visible to my Managers :( ...

It looks like when an Opportunity Owner (Donation Owner) is set to someone whom is in the Role & Profile of Admin, then our Managers cant see it.  But if the owner is switched, to someone unrelated, whom is in the Role and Profile of Manager, then it becomes visible.

Comment: @MikhailNitko How are you testing this? After you've setup your sharing rule and a Manager user navigates to the record (searching, or using the Id in the URL) do they see anything? If they do, then are the reports you are using set to 'All Opportunities'?

Comment: The way I'm testing this is, we have two reports, one based on Donations whose owner has a Role & Profile of Manager.  And another report on Donations whose owner has a Role & Profile of Admin.  What I am doing is going into the sharing rules, and enabling sharing of Opportunities from an Admin Role owner, to Manager Role, or to any group that Managers belong to (as I've been testing).  I then go and open the report with Donations entered by an Admin, and I switch the hierarchy view to Manager, at which point all records dissappear :(